# <iframe> gets src from <select> but uses submit button

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

http://communitychessclub.com/blog.php (This solution was answered in a previous post works but requires a submit button when I suspect a javascript mouseup would work.)

Could this issue be addressed?

```
<script>
document.getElementById("dynamic_selection").addEventListener('change', function()
{
submitted_1();
});
</script>


<script>
function submitted_1(){
link = document.getElementById("dynamic_selection").value;
document.getElementById("movie").src = "https://www.youtube.com/embed/"+link+"?VQ=HD1080&rel=0&amp;showinfo=0";
}
</script>

<div style = "display:table; margin:2rem auto">

<form onsubmit="return false;">

<select id="dynamic_selection">
<option value="" selected>Music</option>
<option value="bnpRjLfr-yU">The Dangerous Type - The Police Cars &#9836; 
</option>
<option value="VUcBDUIeOFU">Mr. Fingers Mystery Of Love</option>
<option value="zoQ5vy9krOY">Sleepwalk - New version of Shadows Classic</option>
<option value="WdSHmipA0uc">Peter Tosh - That's What They Will Do &#9836;</option>
<option value="YrpL4n_wonY">Ram Jam - Black Betty</option>

</select> <button onclick="submitted_1()">Submit</button>
</form>

</div>
```

Comment: Have you made any attempt at addressing the issues? Have you researched anything?

Comment: Yes. I have fixed the blank space issue (and edited the post) by adding a temporary placeholder video.

Answer (score 0):

So, you want a new movie to show, when you have selected it in your `<select>`?

You can try:

```
document.getElementById("dynamic_selection").addEventListener('change', function()
{
submitted_1();
});
```

Now `submitted_1()` is called whenever you input/selects a new value, and you don't need the button.

Note: The `change` event does not fire until you lose focus on the `select`.

Comment: Looks like a right paren is left out. And the code fails to function as indicated. Can you revise, please?

Comment: Huh... It still fails.

Comment: Ehh, what happens, when you select a value?

Comment: Nothing. Is it possible that the link = document.getElementById("dynamic_selection").value; is not valid?

Comment: Do you click somewhere else on the document to change focus?

Comment: No that makes no sense to me. Clicking on a select option is proper. But if possible I would like to have onmouseup select the option. Can you do that?

Comment: Just change 'change' to 'mouseup'.

Comment: I tried that. Nothing happens. The mouseup just does nothing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180698/discussion-between-verlager-and-poul-bak).